# Flutter - problem with adding native dependency on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, flutter, dart, cmake

I'm trying to build Flutter with native C++ dependency, but every time I try to add CMake subproject it fails due to a problem with creating a directory. It's probably something simple, but it's really hard to find any guide on how to add dependencies for the Windows platform, so I'm improvising (a lot).

---

**Flutter Doctor summary:**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.376], locale pl-PL)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

---

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a new Flutter project with support for the Windows platform.
2. Copy library (e.g. [DirectXText](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex)) into the project root folder.
3. Add the library in the `[project]\windows\CMakeLists.txt` by adding a subdirectory (`add_subdirectory(../DirectXTex "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_directxtex")`):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(stackoverflow_windows_question LANGUAGES CXX)

set(BINARY_NAME "stackoverflow_windows_question")

cmake_policy(SET CMP0063 NEW)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/lib")

# Configure build options.
get_property(IS_MULTICONFIG GLOBAL PROPERTY GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG)
if(IS_MULTICONFIG)
  set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug;Profile;Release"
    CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
else()
  if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug" CACHE
      STRING "Flutter build mode" FORCE)
    set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS
      "Debug" "Profile" "Release")
  endif()
endif()

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_PROFILE "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_PROFILE "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_PROFILE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_PROFILE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")

# Use Unicode for all projects.
add_definitions(-DUNICODE -D_UNICODE)

# Compilation settings that should be applied to most targets.
function(APPLY_STANDARD_SETTINGS TARGET)
  target_compile_features(${TARGET} PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
  target_compile_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE /W4 /WX /wd"4100")
  target_compile_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE /EHsc)
  target_compile_definitions(${TARGET} PRIVATE "_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0")
  target_compile_definitions(${TARGET} PRIVATE "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:_DEBUG>")
endfunction()

set(FLUTTER_MANAGED_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/flutter")

# Flutter library and tool build rules.
add_subdirectory(${FLUTTER_MANAGED_DIR})

# Application build
add_subdirectory("runner")

# Generated plugin build rules, which manage building the plugins and adding
# them to the application.
include(flutter/generated_plugins.cmake)

add_subdirectory(../DirectXTex "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_directxtex") # NEW LINE

# === Installation ===
# Support files are copied into place next to the executable, so that it can
# run in place. This is done instead of making a separate bundle (as on Linux)
# so that building and running from within Visual Studio will work.
set(BUILD_BUNDLE_DIR "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${BINARY_NAME}>")
# Make the "install" step default, as it's required to run.
set(CMAKE_VS_INCLUDE_INSTALL_TO_DEFAULT_BUILD 1)
if(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${BUILD_BUNDLE_DIR}" CACHE PATH "..." FORCE)
endif()

set(INSTALL_BUNDLE_DATA_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/data")
set(INSTALL_BUNDLE_LIB_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")

install(TARGETS ${BINARY_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}"
  COMPONENT Runtime)

install(FILES "${FLUTTER_ICU_DATA_FILE}" DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BUNDLE_DATA_DIR}"
  COMPONENT Runtime)

install(FILES "${FLUTTER_LIBRARY}" DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BUNDLE_LIB_DIR}"
  COMPONENT Runtime)

if(PLUGIN_BUNDLED_LIBRARIES)
  install(FILES "${PLUGIN_BUNDLED_LIBRARIES}"
    DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BUNDLE_LIB_DIR}"
    COMPONENT Runtime)
endif()

# Fully re-copy the assets directory on each build to avoid having stale files
# from a previous install.
set(FLUTTER_ASSET_DIR_NAME "flutter_assets")
install(CODE "
  file(REMOVE_RECURSE \"${INSTALL_BUNDLE_DATA_DIR}/${FLUTTER_ASSET_DIR_NAME}\")
  " COMPONENT Runtime)
install(DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BUILD_DIR}/${FLUTTER_ASSET_DIR_NAME}"
  DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BUNDLE_DATA_DIR}" COMPONENT Runtime)

# Install the AOT library on non-Debug builds only.
install(FILES "${AOT_LIBRARY}" DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BUNDLE_DATA_DIR}"
  CONFIGURATIONS Profile;Release
  COMPONENT Runtime)
```

4. Try to build it in verbose mode:

```
flutter build windows -v
```

5. Wait for the build to fail:

```
[  +78 ms] PostBuildEvent:
[        ]   setlocal
[        ]   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
[        ]   if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
[        ]   :cmEnd
[        ]   endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
[        ]   :cmErrorLevel
[        ]   exit /b %1
[        ]   :cmDone
[        ]   if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
[        ]   :VCEnd
[  +83 ms]   -- Install configuration: "Release"
[   +1 ms]   CMake Error at stackoverflow_windows_question_directxtex/cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
[        ]     file cannot create directory:
[        ]     C:/Users/jbili/Documents/Flutter-Projects/stackoverflow_windows_question/build/windows/$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:stackoverflow_windows_question>/lib.
[        ]     Maybe need administrative privileges.
[        ]   Call Stack (most recent call first):
[        ]     cmake_install.cmake:47 (include)
[   +7 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: Polecenie „setlocal [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +1 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P
cmake_install.cmake [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd” zostało zakończone przez kod 1. [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] Kompilowanie projektu „C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj” wykonane (domyślne elementy docelowe) — NIEPOWODZENIE.
[        ] Kompilacja NIE POWIODŁA SIĘ.
[        ] „C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj” (domyślny element docelowy) (1)->
[        ] (element docelowy PostBuildEvent) ->
[        ]   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: Polecenie „setlocal [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P
cmake_install.cmake [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd” zostało zakończone przez kod 1. [C:\Users\jbili\Documents\Flutter-Projects\stackoverflow_windows_question\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ]     Ostrzeżenia: 0
[        ]     Liczba błędów: 1
[        ] Czas, który upłynął: 00:00:41.72
[  +12 ms] Building Windows application... (completed in 44,1s)
[        ] "flutter windows" took 44 278ms.
[   +2 ms] Build process failed.
[        ] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      _runBuild (package:flutter_tools/src/windows/build_windows.dart:299:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      buildWindows (package:flutter_tools/src/windows/build_windows.dart:78:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      BuildWindowsCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_windows.dart:55:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[  +69 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 68ms
[        ] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

---

As you can see it fails, because it can't create directory `C:/Users/jbili/Documents/Flutter-Projects/stackoverflow_windows_question/build/windows/$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:stackoverflow_windows_question>/lib`, because the directory path looks incorrectly. I think that `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:stackoverflow_windows_question>` has not been converted at some point by CMake, but I don't know why.

Could you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but Have you tried to run the script using Admin privileges, this may solve your problem because the error said "Maybe need administrative privileges."

Comment: Yes, I tried running this project with elevated privileges, but it didn't help. I think I missed some "Flutter Magic" in the `CMakeLists.txt`. I don't know what exactly I missed, because adding desktop libraries in Flutter is undocumented.